# R - Error in odbcDriverConnect("") : object 'C_RODBCDriverConnect' not found

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc, r-package

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server from R Studio. I've installed RODBC package.
But when I try to create a `dobcDriveConnect()` handle, I get this error:

```
Error in odbcDriverConnect("") :  object 'C_RODBCDriverConnect' not found
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I'm  using Windows 7, R 3.4.2, RODBC v1.3-15

Thanks

Comment: Try reinstalling the package

Comment: I tried that, it's not working. This is a work computer for a bank. so the system is locked down pretty tightly. I'm having issues with other packages also, I'm thinking it might be an issue with the security here. 
Maybe someone had a similar issue before?